# How to increase the evaluation speed of this somewhat complicated table / matrix operation?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, list-manipulation, summation

I'd like to calculate the following one-dimensional array:

```
OneDimArray = Table[(Norm[Sum[ MatrixA[[i,j]]VectorB[[j]],{j,N}]])^2,{i,N}]
```

However this takes a very long time when `N` goes up; for `N = 1500` it already takes ~40 minutes (on my MacBook Pro).

I've heard there are certain functions in Mathematica that are optimized for speed; could I employ those (and if so: which ones?) to speed up this calculation?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Steven

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just do `Abs[Dot[MatrixA, VectorB]]^2`. By the way, don't use capitalized words for user-defined symbols so as not to conflict with *Mathematica*'s built-in functions, which all start with capital letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have plenty of redundant operations here:

The equivalent code is (where `a` is a matrix and `b` is a list of 3-vectors):

```
Map[Norm[#]^2 &, a . b];
```

---

I have:

```
n = 500;
a = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
b = RandomReal[1, {n, 3}];

oneDimArray = 
   Table[(Norm[Sum[a[[i, j]] b[[j]], {j, n}]])^2, {i, 
     n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {46.5618, Null} *)

oneDimArrayMap = Map[Norm[#]^2 &, a.b]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000621823, Null} *)

oneDimArray == oneDimArrayMap
(* True *)
```

Thus, using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) almost 70000 times faster than manual loops.

Comment: Apologies; my question wasn't complete/correct: the vectorB I'm working with in this case is actually an array of 3-dimensional vectors -- and, to be as complete as possible now, the MatrixA the eigenvectors of a Hamiltonian of an excitonic vibrational system. (The physics, for context: To calculate the IR absorption intensities of the normal modes of such a system one has to first multiply the local mode vectors in VectorB with their respective eigenvector contribution, then sum these products to get the normal mode vector; the intensity of the mode is then given by norm[NormalModeVector]^2.)

Comment: @StevenR Than you still can utilize the `Dot` with a simple `Map` on it. On  random matrix-vector I have 70000 speed up. Try this code on your data and let us know.

Comment: Wow, indeed, that gives a 45000-fold speed up for my specific matrices, thank you very much for the great advice m0nhawk!

Comment: If you replace `Norm[#]^2 &` with `#.# &`, it should even be quicker.

Comment: @J.M. I have tried it, but no performance improvements, timing is the same for me (in *Mathematica* 10.3).

Comment: I'm now faced with a similar slowdown for a slightly more complicated spectral calculation. I feel like it can also be improved using Map (or MapAt), but my lack of experience doesn't help here - would you guys maybe know whether mapping can work here too:

    'Table[
     Sum[
      Sum[     
       var1[[k, i]] var1[[k, j]] ((var2[[i]] - var2[[j]]).(var3[[i]]\[Cross] var3[[j]]))   
       , {i, length}], {j, length}]
     , {k, length}]'

Comment: Sorry, this time properly formatted:

`Table[
     Sum[
      Sum[     
       var1[[k, i]] var1[[k, j]] ((var2[[i]] - var2[[j]]).(var3[[i]]\[Cross] var3[[j]]))   
       , {i, length}], {j, length}]
     , {k, length}]`